# How can I move an object randomly in small area from his current position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.transform.position = RandomVector(0.1f, 0.5f);
    }

    private Vector3 RandomVector(float min, float max)
    {
        var x = Random.Range(min, max);
        var y = Random.Range(min, max);
        var z = Random.Range(min, max);

        return new Vector3(transform.position.x + x, transform.position.y + y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

I want it to move in small area randomly between 0.1 and 0.5 but since I did + x and + y it keep changing position and move far far nonstop.

```
return new Vector3(transform.position.x + x, transform.position.y + y, transform.position.z);
```

What should I do instead transform.position.x + x and transform.position.x + y ?

Comment: `private Vector3 RandomVector(float min, float max)
    {
        var x = Random.Range(min, max);
        var y = Random.Range(min, max);
        var z = Random.Range(min, max);

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }`

Comment: What is your goal? Is it something like patrol behavior, or something different?You get weird results because you keep calling the RandomVector in every frame so in every frame you will move your object by a random value.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted :
The script is attached to a cube.
Another script is attached to the sci-fi drone I have that all is do is making the drone LookAt the cube.

That's it this create a lost control effect of the sci-fi drone shooting out of control.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Vector3> waypoints = new List<Vector3>();  // Hom many items you want, will show in Inspector
    public float speed;

    private int current = 0;
    private float WPradius = 1;

    private void Start()
    {
        GetRandom();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveBetweenWaypoints();
    }

    private void GetRandom()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            waypoints.Add(new Vector3(Random.Range(transform.position.x, transform.position.x + 3f),
                Random.Range(transform.position.y, transform.position.y + 3f),
                transform.position.z));
        }
    }

    private void MoveBetweenWaypoints()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(waypoints[current], transform.position) < WPradius)
        {
            current = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Count);
            if(current >= waypoints.Count)
            {
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[current], Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```